# Does ONNX increase inference efficiancy comparted to pytorch model?

Tags: optimization, pytorch, onnx, inference

So I have been using Hugginface wave2vecCTC for speech recognition. I want to do as much optimization as possible.  One way I have found during my searches was to turn the model into ONNX. So I wrote a Python log script to keep track of GPU, CPU, and runtime duration, with different settings ( Half options-float16-, CPU or GPU, and different batch sizes). Oddly, the Pytorch model outperforms ONNX  one. So my question is, is this normal, I thought ONNX is much more efficient when it comes to optimization and inference time. Here is the code I have been using for  benchmarking :

```
# from onnxconverter_common import auto_mixed_precision
import os
import onnxruntime
import torch
import psutil
import time
import threading
import pandas as pd
import librosa
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from onnxconverter_common import float16
import onnx
import GPUtil
import argparse
import subprocess
def get_gpu_stats():
    command = "nvidia-smi --query-gpu=utilization.gpu,memory.used,memory.total --format=csv,nounits,noheader"#
    result = subprocess.run(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True, text=True)
    output_lines = result.stdout.strip().split('\n')
    gpu_stats = []
    for line in output_lines:
        values = line.split(',')
        utilization = float(values[0])
        memory_used = int(values[1])
        memory_total = int(values[2])
    # return output_lines[0].split(',')
    return [utilization , memory_used, memory_total]
def load_and_prepare_model_inputs (model_path, inputs_, export_onnx, halved, device):
    # Load the model from ONNX if it exists; otherwise, export and load it
    model = Wav2Vec2ForCTC.from_pretrained(model_path )

    temp  =  "halved" if halved else ""
    ONNX_Half_Dir = os.path.join("ONNX-Models",  f"model" + temp + ".onnx")
    ONNXmodelDir = os.path.join("ONNX-Models",  f"model.onnx")
    dtype = torch.float16 if halved else torch.float32
    inputs = inputs_.input_values
    masks = inputs_.attention_mask
    model.eval()

    if export_onnx :
        # dataType= torch.float16 if halved else  torch.float32

        if not os.path.exists(ONNXmodelDir):
            os.makedirs("ONNX-Models",exist_ok = True)
            dummy_input = torch.unsqueeze(inputs[0] , dim=0) 
            dummy_masks = torch.unsqueeze(masks[0].to(dummy_input.dtype) , dim=0) 
            torch.onnx.export(
                model,
                (dummy_input, dummy_masks),
                ONNXmodelDir,
                # f"model.onnx",
                input_names=["input", "masks"],
                output_names=["output"],
                dynamic_axes={"input": {0: "batch_size", 1: "sequence_length"},
                            "masks": {0: "batch_size", 1: "sequence_length"},
                            "output": {0: "batch_size", 1: "sequence_length"}},
                opset_version=11,  # You can adjust the opset version based on your needs
            )
            print ("Finished saving the ONNX model")
            if halved and not os.path.exists(ONNX_Half_Dir):
                model = onnx.load(ONNXmodelDir)
                model_fp16 = float16.convert_float_to_float16(model)
                onnx.save(model_fp16, ONNX_Half_Dir)
                del model_fp16
        options = onnxruntime.SessionOptions()
        options.enable_profiling = True
        provider  = 'CPUExecutionProvider' if device == 'cpu' else 'CUDAExecutionProvider'
        Dir = ONNX_Half_Dir if halved else ONNXmodelDir
        model = onnxruntime.InferenceSession(Dir
                                            , sess_options=options
                                            , providers= [provider])
        input_name = model.get_inputs()[0].name
        mask_name = model.get_inputs()[1].name
        output_name = model.get_outputs()[0].name
        inputs = [[output_name], {input_name: inputs.to(dtype).numpy(),
                    mask_name: inputs.to(dtype).numpy()}]
        print("#############################\n Finished loading  the ONNX model and the Inputs\n#############################")
    #transfer the model and data to cpu or gpu
    else:
        # if not halved:
        #
model = model.to(torch.float32)
        model = model.half() if halved else model 
        inputs = inputs.half() if halved else inputs 
        masks = masks.half() if halved else masks 
        model = model.to(device)
        inputs = [inputs.to(device), masks.to(device)]
        print("#############################\nFinished loading  the Pytorch model and the Inputs\n#############################")

    return model, inputs

# Function to perform inference and measure time and memory usage
def inference(model, inputs, device, halved, batch_size, export_onnx=False):
    fileNames , inputs = inputs
    gpu_first_stat = get_gpu_stats()
    result = {  'time': 0,
                # 'gpu_memory_reserved_amount': [getMB(torch.cuda.memory_reserved()) if device == 'cuda' else 0],
                # 'gpu_memory_util_amount': [getMB(torch.cuda.memory_allocated()) if device == 'cuda' else 0],
                'gpu_utilization':[gpu_first_stat[0]],
                'gpu_memory_used':[gpu_first_stat[1]],
                'gpu_memory_total':[gpu_first_stat[2]],
                'cpu_memory_util_percent': [round(psutil.virtual_memory().percent,3)],
                'cpu_util_percent': [round(psutil.cpu_percent(),3)],
                'cpu_memory_util_amount': [getMB(psutil.virtual_memory().used)],
                'decoder_time':[],
                'done': False}
    # Initialize the thread for memory monitoring
    mode =  "onnx" if export_onnx else "pytorch"
    memory_thread = threading.Thread(target=monitor_memory, args=(device, result))
    memory_thread.start()
    model_time_track = []
    decoder_time_track = []
    # Inference
    if export_onnx:
        for _ in range(5):
            # Perform inference 10 times for more accurate timing
            start_time = time.time()
            logits = model.run(inputs[0], inputs[1] )
            model_time_track.append(time.time() - start_time)
            predicted_ids = logits[0].argmax(axis=-1)
            decoder_start_time  = time.time()
            predicted_sentences = processor.batch_decode(predicted_ids)
            decoder_time_track.append(time.time() - decoder_start_time)

    else:
        inputs, masks = inputs 
        for _ in range(5): 
            with torch.no_grad():
                # Perform inference 10 times for more accurate timing
                mdoel_start_time = time.time()
                logits = model(inputs, attention_mask =masks).logits
                model_time_track.append(time.time() - mdoel_start_time)
                decoder_start_time  = time.time()
                predicted_ids = torch.argmax(logits, dim=-1)
                predicted_sentences = processor.batch_decode(predicted_ids)
                decoder_time_track.append(time.time() -decoder_start_time)
        del masks

    result['outputs'] = predicted_sentences
    result["filenames"] = fileNames

    # Stop memory monitoring thread
    result
    result['done'] = True
    del model
    del inputs
    memory_thread.join()
    model_time, decoder_time = round(np.median(model_time_track[2:]),4) ,round(np.median(decoder_time_track),4) 

    # Calculate time and save results
    result = {key: value for key,value  in result.items() if isinstance(value, list) and len(value) > 1}
    result = manage_dictionary_lengths(result)
    overall_stats =  [
                                      round(interval*np.sum(result['cpu_util_percent']),2)
                                    , round(interval*np.sum(result['gpu_memory_used']),1)
                                    , round (interval*np.sum(result['gpu_utilization']), 2)
                                    , round(interval*np.sum(result['cpu_memory_util_percent']),1)
                                    , round(interval*np.sum(result['cpu_memory_util_amount']),1 )
                        ]
    folder_name = f'Inference_logs_{mode}_{device}_halved_{halved}_batch_{batch_size}'
    overall_results[folder_name] = [  mode, device, halved, batch_size
                                    , model_time, decoder_time 
                                    ,
overall
_stats[0]
                                    , overall_stats[1]
                                    , overall_stats[2]
                                    , overall_stats[3]
                                    , overall_stats[4]
                                    , round(overall_stats[0] / batch_size, 4)
                                    , round(overall_stats[1] / batch_size, 4)
                                    , round(overall_stats[2] / batch_size, 4)
                                    , round(overall_stats[3] / batch_size, 4)
                                    , round(overall_stats[4] / batch_size, 4)
                                    , round(model_time / batch_size, 5)
                                    , round(decoder_time  / batch_size, 5)
                                ]
    plot_individual_results(result,mode,  device, halved, batch_size, [model_time_track], [decoder_time_track] ,os.getcwd())


# Example usage
if name == "__main__":
    # parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="ONNX Inference Benchmark Script")
    # parser.add_argument("--modelDir", type=str, default="../ImanSavedData", help="Location of the model folder")
    # args = parser.parse_args()
    # model_dir = args.modelDir
    test_path = "Samples"
    speech_arrays = []
    fileNames = [f for f in os.listdir(test_path) if f.endswith('.wav') or f.endswith('.mp3')]
    # fileNames = ['11.wav']
    paths = [os.path.join(test_path,f) for f in  fileNames]
    speech_arrays = [librosa.load(path, sr=16_000)[0] for path in paths]
    # Define configurations
    # devices = ['cuda'] if torch.cuda.is_available() else ['cpu']
    devices = ['cuda']#,'cpu']
    halved_options = [ False]#True, 
    batch_sizes = [1,5,11]  # Adjust based on your needs
    model_dir = "./model/"
    # Perform inference for different configurations
    for onnxmode in [ True, False]:#
        for device in devices:
            for halved in halved_options:
                for batch_size in batch_sizes:
                    model_dir = "./model/"
                    model_dir =  model_dir#+'_half' if halved else model_dir
                    processor = Wav2Vec2Processor.from_pretrained(model_dir)
                    inputs = processor(speech_arrays[:batch_size], sampling_rate=16_000, return_tensors="pt", padding="max_length",max_length =240320, truncation= True  )
                    # Load and prepare the model
                    halved = False if device=='cpu' else halved
                    model, inputs = load_and_prepare_model_inputs(model_dir, inputs, export_onnx=onnxmode, halved=halved, device=device)
                    # Perform inference
                    fileNamesTemp = fileNames[:batch_size]
                    inference(model, [fileNamesTemp , inputs], device, halved, batch_size, export_onnx=onnxmode)

    custom_index = [
               "mode","device", "halved", "batch-size" , "model-time" , "decoder-time" , 
               "cpu-util-percent", "gpu-memory-used", "gpu-utilization", 
               "cpu-memory-util-percent", "cpu-memory-util-amount",
               'cpu-util-percent-batch-size-gain', "gpu-memory-used-batch-size-gain" , "gpu-utilization-batch-size-gain",
               "cpu-memory-util-percent-batch-size-gain", "cpu-memory-util-amount-batch-size-gain",
               "model-time-batch-size-gain" ,  "decoder-time-batch-size-gain"   
               ]
    df = pd.DataFrame(overall_results, index=custom_index)
    df.to_excel('overall_logs.xlsx',index=True ) #float_format='%.4f' ,index=True )
    print(f"**** device:{device}-halfed:{halved}-batchsize:{batch_size}, isONNX:{onnxmode}-- Done  *****\n\n")
```

**And here are the benchmark results:**
[image]